# I need to exclude the specific two-character string `[?` from a regex match search

Tags: javascript, regex, highlight, mark.js

I am using this regex string to find all periods and exclamation and question marks that have white space around them or are not part of decimals:

```
/\.(?=\s|$)|\?(?=\s|$)|\!(?=\s|$)/g
```

I’m using mark.js to highlight this RegEx string. How can I modify this string (or use another one) that won’t highlight a question mark that comes immediately after a bracket, or `[?`

Here is my code:

```js
function Highlight() {
var instance = new Mark(document.getElementById("example"));

instance.unmark();
instance.markRegExp(/\.(?=\s|$)|\?(?=\s|$)|\!(?=\s|$)/g);

}

window.onload = Highlight();
```

```css
mark {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
<p>This is an example paragraph. I would like all the periods to be highlighted. Woohoo! This works very well! Yay! Alright, onto question marks. This is demo2. [? flagged ?] 5.5 is a number. 0.3374 is another number. Does this work?</p>
</div>
```

Mark.js also has an `unmark()` method to unmark things, but I don’t know how to use RegEx with `unmark()`. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind behind the `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookbehind `(?<!\[)` is inserted before `\?` to regex which means that the regex will take the `?` whose preceding character is not `[`. You can add any other characters inside the negative lookbehind set to exclude `?` with other preceding characters.

Warning : This is not supported in all browsers.

Alternative solution would be to use normal negate set `[^\[]` before `?` like this `/\.(?=\s|$)|[^\[]\?(?=\s|$)|\!(?=\s|$)/g`. But this regex selects the preceding character as well. You have to handle it in your code.

```js
function Highlight() {
var instance = new Mark(document.getElementById("example"));

instance.unmark();
instance.markRegExp(/\.(?=\s|$)|(?<!\[)\?(?=\s|$)|\!(?=\s|$)/g);

}

window.onload = Highlight();
```

```css
mark {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
<p>This is an example paragraph. I would like all the periods to be highlighted. Woohoo! This works very well! Yay! Alright, onto question marks. This is demo2. [? flagged ?] 5.5 is a number. 0.3374 is another number. Does this work?</p>
</div>
```